# Создать экземпляр класса в абстрактном классе, который наследуется дочерним классом

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

У меня есть некий абстрактный класс с методом, который реализует сериализацию дочернего класса, это работает до тех пор пока я не добавил метаданные дочернему классу в виде декоратора, используя ReflectMetadata, в этом случае метаданные не сериализуются, соответственно и не могут быть десериализованы, мне не нужно их сериализовавать, нужно лишь восстановить обратно при десериализации. Следующая реализация показалась мне логичной

```
export abstract class LocalStorageModel {

  serialize(): string {
    return JSON.stringify(this)
  }

  deserialize(serializedString: string): LocalStorageModel {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(serializedString)
    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      mdpn,
      Reflect.getMetadata(
        mdpn,
        new (this.constructor as LocalStorageModelConstructor)()
      ),
      parsed.prototype
    )
    return
  }
}
```

Однако в консоли я вижу сообщение

```
class constructor ExampleClass cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Где ExampleClass это дочерний класс, который наследует абстрактный класс.

Использую Webpack и Typescript

Comment: что такое `mdpn`?

Comment: Имя свойства метаданных

Comment: попробуй сделать [mcve]

Comment: пока подумаю над примером, я переформулирую вопрос на "как создать экземпляр класса A в абстрактном классе, который класс A наследует".  Чтобы понимать, возможно ли это вообще, чтобы понять где именно возникает проблема

Comment: если ты знаешь какой тип ты хочешь создать то его и создаешь, если не знаешь - то и не создашь

Comment: мне нужно получить конструктор класса который наследовал абстрактный класс. Видимо это не возможно, тогда как я могу вернуть метаданные утерянные при JSON.stringify().

Comment: ты их можешь точно так же сериализовать в специальное поле, например

Comment: Как вариант, но я не хочу переносить постороннюю информацию в JSON и её модификацию пользователем

Comment: тогда по json ты не сможешь понять какой тип тебе нужен и следовательно не сможешь создать экземпляр. Если же ты знаешь тип - тогда и проблемы нет, просто сразу создавай его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать прототип конструктора, чтобы получить доступ к метаданным без создания экземпляра

```
deserialize<T>(serializedString: string): T {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(serializedString)
    for (const key of Reflect.getMetadataKeys(this.constructor.prototype)) {
      Reflect.defineMetadata(
        key,
        Reflect.getMetadata(key, this.constructor.prototype),
        parsed
      )
    }
    return parsed as T
  }
```

Через экземпляр

```
Reflect.getMetadata(key, instance)
```

Через конструктор

```
Reflect.getMetadata(key, Constructor.prototype)
```

Таким образом я избегаю использования new, из-за которого и возникала проблема